# Реализация службы виндовс без pywin32

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

Не нравится реализация передачи параметров и сопоставление службы через реестр. Pure python решение интересно

Comment: подозреваю я, что "python решение интересно" уже есть у вас )) ждем...

Comment: @Jack_oS пока нет;) перед тем как открыть docs.microsoft.com тут спрашиваю нет ли велосипедов)